# Why is the mage book grayed out on Jaheira?

Tags: baldurs-gate

She has a heal spell that is single use unless it is memorized. Her mage book screen is grey so I can't manipulate it. Is she just worthless or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a long time, but I believe in Baldur's Gate there's a distinction between "Mage Spells" (which are in the mage book) and "Priest Spells" which are in the Priest scroll.

Have you checked her Priest scroll?

Comment: Ah yes I just found this screen. Still, why does it disappear after casting? It did come back after staying at the inn but does it mean that it is one time per day?

Comment: Like I said, it's been a while...  the D&D system I believe requires that mages and priests (and related classes) must prepare a number of charges of their spells ahead of time.  Resting restores those "charges."  As she levels up, she'll gain more memorization slots, and therefore be able to either cast low numbers of a variety of spells per day, or cast a few spells many times per day.

Comment: Correct, casting is once per day. Mages and priests are notoriously underpowered at low level. Don't worry, they get a lot better.

Comment: It's not exactly once a day. You can cast again after resting 8 hours.